# right continuous implies countably additive

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, probability-theory

Let $F:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $ be a monotonically increasing function. Let $\mu_F$ be defined on the half open real intervals such that $\mu_F((a,b]) = F(b) - F(a)$. Then $\mu_F$ is countably additive if $F$ is right-continuous. (defined [here](https://books.google.com.au/books?id=Y9YcRnvfhtYC&pg=PA62&lpg=PA62) ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6mOJU.png)), definition has a bigger domain but I think restricting it here still works).

But why is this? I've proved finite additivity. Also tried to use the continuity of probability measures, but I couldn't get that proof to work here since the half open intervals isn't a $\sigma$-algebra.

Comment: Is it true that the set $\tilde{I}$ contains only half-open intervals? Then you only need to verify countable additivity in particular cases: $(a,b] = \bigcup_i (a_i,b_i]$.  Can you add a definition of $\tilde{I}$ from the book?

Comment: @thomas If it's bigger then countable additivity still holds for a subset of $\bar{I}$ right? I haven't read the book entirely but from that page it seems that $\bar{I}$ includes $(a, b], (-\infty, b), (a, \infty), (-\infty, \infty)$. But I'm having trouble verifying it in the case you describe.

Comment: I do not understand the first sentence of your last comment. $\tilde{I}$ does not include sets of the form $(-\infty,b)$ but $(-\infty,b]$; the other sets are fine. Try to write down possible situations which may occur in the particular case I described: an interval as the **disjoint** union of intervals.

Comment: @thomas You're right, typo. In the first sentence I mean that for $\mu_F$ restricted to a subset of $\bar{I}$ from the book, in this case the set of open half intervals, I think countable additivity should hold if it holds for $\mu_F$. I can prove the case where there are a finite number of disjoint intervals, but when theres a countable number of them I have no idea what to do (when $(a, b] = \bigcup_{i=1}^\infty (a_i, b_i]$).

Comment: @thomas I'm not sure about the possible situations you describe either except for finite/infinite, could you give me a hint or post an answer?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here's a proof idea which I got working in the end, use the proof for countable additivity of the length function for intervals (http://www.maths.tcd.ie/~richardt/MA2224/MA2224-ch2.pdf Proposition 2.1.12), and where it uses $\epsilon/2^n$, we take a $\delta_i$ s.t. $0 < t - d_i <= \delta_i$ we have that $F(t) - F(d_i) < \epsilon/2^i$. Nothing else changes much.

The key is the Heine Borel theorem, it reduces the countable case to a finite case, which is easy to handle.

Comment: The idea looks good. If you write out the proof you will also see where right-continuity of $F$ matters.

Comment: @thomas It happens when taking the deltas.

Comment: Really, the key is how you expand on $\mu_F$ on the algebra of all intervals using the left-side limits of F.

Comment: Then you can use right-continuity to find $a'$ such that $[a,b]\supseteq ]a',b]$ and $\mu_F'([a,b])\leq \mu_F'(]a',b])+\varepsilon$ and $b'$ respectively such that $]a,b[\subseteq ]a,b']$ and $\mu_F'(]a,b[)\geq \mu_F'(]a,b'])-\varepsilon$.

Comment: The proof you linked works for all regular pre measures with respect to a topology for which Heine Borel holds for luck of a better word (analgous to regular measures). But you have to find the regular pre measure first, because otherwise you are working with non existing $\mu_F([a,b])$ or $\mu_F(]a,b[)$.